# How to deal with exceptions in IO::Socket::INET?

Tags: raku

Assume there's no application listening at port 12340 in localhost.

Shouldn't the command below print "error" ?

```
$ raku -e "IO::Socket::INET.new(:host('localhost'), :port(12340)) or die 'error'"
Could not connect socket: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

Comment: It dies before being able to die... It should return a `Failure`, but it does not. Might be a bug. I've been checking out source, and looks like it's something that happens deep in MoarVM code and is not caught and returned as `Failure` at the Rakudo level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current implementation of `nqp::connect`, the underlying logic to make the connection, throws an `X::AdHoc` exception.  Having `IO::Socket::INET.new` return a `Failure` if not able to connect, would make more sense to me indeed.

I've created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/4957) to create this behaviour.

Until then, you can use the same code change locally:

```
sub connect($host, $port) {
    CATCH { return .Failure }
    IO::Socket::INET.new(:$host, :$port)
}

connect('localhost', 12340) or die 'error';
```

Comment: I used `try` and ` if $!`, it works well for me ... but I would like to get the error number (1225 in Windows, 111 in Linux), and couldn't find a way to do that

Comment: That'd be the other way  :-)